# How to stop my 8 year old son from doubting and/or speaking against the existence of God?

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, development, middle-childhood, religion

I am a Muslim, and so is my husband. Our 8 year old son is refusing to learn how to offer namaz and does not offer prayers either, and in his school, he has been slapped and beaten by teachers for questioning the righteousness of God. (In my country, which is Pakistan, it is common for boys to be beaten to motivate them to learn, this happens in every school with the exclusion of international ones, which are extremely expensive.)

Recently, he came back home with half of his face completely red. When I asked him what happened, he told me that his teacher slapped him hard for asking "Why is God so hungry for praise?" and although this doesn't sound too much cruel in English, in Urdu, it was said in a very harsh and informal manner, which was "Khuda itna bhuka kiyun hai tarifen or namaz key liye?"

He keeps doing these things often, and I am afraid that one day, he will get us in a very bad situation. I do not want the scholar at school or anybody to say that we should kill him, which is becoming more and more possible. (In Pakistan, there is a law set by the government that anybody, of any age, will be hanged for speaking vilely against God.)

I cannot ask anybody for help in this case, the answer will very surely be "Beat the blasphemy out of him!" and I do not want that.

Is there a way I can make my son realize that there is a God, or if not, then **how can I teach my son not to say things like these in front of anybody ever again and just listen? (We have already tried telling him nicely, but he never acts accordingly.)**

Comment: Sana -- if you have already tried to talk to him without any result, what are you wanting in terms of advice?

Comment: Edited to make the question itself clearer, but as Erica says, what is it you are looking for? He is already being beaten and slapped, and there is a threat of hanging - if these aren't enough, then I'm not sure what else you can expect.

Comment: You may wish to read http://islam.stackexchange.com/ - which may have more formal or approved guidance

Comment: Please keep comments respectful, constructive, and on topic.

Comment: SanaAhmed, we understand that this situation is very stressful for you, and we'd like to help. But as @Erica asked, what exactly are you asking? If you've asked him to stop, punishment at school doesn't work, and it appears you can't go to the teachers to get them to leave your son alone, what exactly are you asking us to give you advice about? How can we help you? Please edit the question for clarity, and flag for reopening. Thank you.

Comment: Is religion the only part of your son's life which is a source of conflict and concern or is what you described part of a bigger situation?  Also, have you sought help from a child psychologist? Finally, can you find a teacher or religious leader who can answer your son's questions in a way that your son will be satisfied and even encouraged to more observance?

Comment: @anongoodnurse is this question clear now? Can you reopen?

Comment: @AquariusTheGirl - I'm afraid it's not much of an improvement. There are too many issues in this question.

Comment: Explain the issues. Maybe I can try to improve the wording.  @anongoodnurse

Comment: The question has too many issues to be reopened, I think. There are too many things going on there, and in any form that keeps the core the same, there will only be opinion-based answers.

Comment: Voted to reopen - this is like any other question here; we have behavioral problem X, we've tried things A, B, and C and they didn't work, we're looking for other things to try. The context doesn't change the on-topic nature of the question, and not everyone who uses SE lives in happy go-lucky Western liberal democracies, and nothing about the site charter says we should only help people that do.

Comment: Will you do right? While you can, request that your son's birth certificate be altered to the atheist he truly is; else it will be hard for him in the coming years.

Comment: @sanaahmed He actually sounds like a smart kid with a questioning mind and it takes *great* courage to speak out against orthodoxy especially when the certain result is physical harm. You won't make him realise there is a god if he does not see it. Your only hope is to make him stay silent _for his own good_ but be aware that he will reach an age where this will no longer hold.

Comment: Wrong question! Your question should be "How to stop teachers from stopping children about questioning old and out dated belief systems"?

Comment: Your child is smart. You dont need to stop him from enquiring. Self enquiry is the best way to be knowledgeable. Just let him know that unf. this is how the world works. Tell him to train himself to ask these questions to himself instead of looking for them outside. One day universe will give him the answers he is looking for provided his questioning is intensive enough.

Answer (score 17):

Explain it to him as it is, in such abusive environment where they rip the childhood out of the children you have no choice but to be honest as the damage has already been done.

You should explain to him that he might get executed and those whom he love might get hanged, if he is smart enough to ask questions about Allah then he is smart enough to figure out that he has to protect those whom he love

At home the best thing you can do is to allow him to ask these questions, he has all the right to do so.

I wish could you give a better advice but the only other advice I can think of is "get the hell out of there"

Comment: Your experience and advice are useful, but please limit your answer to that which answers the OP's question. See [here](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/986/9327), [here](http://meta.parenting.stackexchange.com/q/890/9327), and other meta questions. The answer as it is now is not very helpful. If you have questions, you can raise then in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting) or meta. Thanks.